# StaticJsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope, using Feather Huzzah (ESP8266) board using MSFT IOT Azure tutorial

Tags: c++, esp8266, azure-iot-hub, arduino-esp8266, adafruit

All,

I have working on a project with my Adafruit Feather Huzzuh.

I am working my way through the following tutorial.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-huzzah-esp8266-get-started](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-feather-huzzah-client-app.git)

Still using Arduino IDE by the way.

The board and the DHT sensor have worked before.

I believe that all packages are installed.

I use the opensource code from:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-feather-huzzah-client-app.git

I get a compiler error when I try to compile the main app.ino file (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-feather-huzzah-client-app/blob/master/app/app.ino).

The error is:

> Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266,
>   80 MHz, Flash, 4M (3M SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only
>   Sketch, 115200"
>
> C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\DHT_online_azure\app\message.ino: In function 'bool
>   readMessage(int, char*)':
>
> message:46: error: 'StaticJsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope
>
> ```
>  StaticJsonBuffer<MESSAGE_MAX_LEN> jsonBuffer;
>
>  ^
> ```
>
> C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\DHT_online_azure\app\message.ino:46:5: note: suggested
>   alternative:
>
> In file included from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson/StaticJsonDocument.hpp:8:0,
>
> ```
>              from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson.hpp:10,
>
>              from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson.h:9,
>
>              from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino project\DHT_online_azure\app\message.ino:2:
> ```
>
> C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson/Memory/StaticJsonBuffer.hpp:110:7:
>   note:   'ArduinoJson::Internals::StaticJsonBuffer'
>
> class StaticJsonBuffer : public Internals::StaticJsonBufferBase {
>
> ```
>    ^
> ```
>
> message:46: error: 'jsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope
>
> ```
>  StaticJsonBuffer<MESSAGE_MAX_LEN> jsonBuffer;
>
>                                    ^
> ```
>
> message:74: error: 'class ArduinoJson::JsonObject' has no member named
>   'printTo'
>
> ```
>  root.printTo(payload, MESSAGE_MAX_LEN);
>
>       ^
> ```
>
> C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\DHT_online_azure\app\message.ino: In function 'void
>   parseTwinMessage(char*)':
>
> message:80: error: 'StaticJsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope
>
> ```
>  StaticJsonBuffer<MESSAGE_MAX_LEN> jsonBuffer;
>
>  ^
> ```
>
> C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\DHT_online_azure\app\message.ino:80:5: note: suggested
>   alternative:
>
> In file included from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson/StaticJsonDocument.hpp:8:0,
>
> ```
>              from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson.hpp:10,
>
>              from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson.h:9,
>
>              from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino project\DHT_online_azure\app\message.ino:2:
> ```
>
> C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson/Memory/StaticJsonBuffer.hpp:110:7:
>   note:   'ArduinoJson::Internals::StaticJsonBuffer'
>
> class StaticJsonBuffer : public Internals::StaticJsonBufferBase {
>
> ```
>    ^
> ```
>
> message:80: error: 'jsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope
>
> ```
>  StaticJsonBuffer<MESSAGE_MAX_LEN> jsonBuffer;
>
>                                    ^
> ```
>
> message:82: error: 'class ArduinoJson::JsonObject' has no member named
>   'success'
>
> ```
>  if (!root.success())
>
>            ^
> ```
>
> message:88: error: 'ArduinoJson::Internals::enable_if >::type' has
>   no member named 'success'
>
> ```
>  if (root["desired"]["interval"].success())
>
>                                  ^
> ```
>
> exit status 1 'StaticJsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

the ArduinoJson.h file is included in the message.ino file.

Is the opensource code supplied by MSFT broken?

Anyone an idea to fix this?

**EDIT 2018-08-23**

The answer from Rita Han - MSFT worked (rollingback the json libary to version 5.x) and I can see now that the device it connected to my access point. I have run into the following problem:

> connected with NETGEAR33, channel 10 dhcp client start...
>   ip:192.168.1.29,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:192.168.1.1 Connected to wifi
>   NETGEAR33. Fetched NTP epoch time is: 28821. deviceId is not found
>   Failed on **IoTHubClient_CreateFromConnectionString**.

I copied the "Connection string - primary key" from the iothubowner menu under settings: shared access policies.

Somehow it does not accept my shared access key. I will google a bit to try and solve this. Help is appreciated.

EDIT 2018-08-03
Solved as well !! I see the measurements in the serial monitor. Need to find a way to change it from DH22 to DH11... but should be able to figure that one out myself. Have seen and fixed the issue on my Adafruit IO try as well.

Comment: Hi borreltijd, I saw [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555386/connecting-sparkfun-esp8266-thing-to-azure-iot-hub) before. You can check my answer to see if it helps.

Comment: Great it worked!

Comment: Hi borreltijd, glad to hear that. If the answer help you solved the issue you can [accept it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error is that you install the ArduinoJson version >= 6. Default version 6.2.3-beta will be installed but **from version 6 and higher JsonBuffer is replaced with JsonDocument**. It is also indicate in the error message:

> C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\DHT_online_azure\app\message.ino:80:5: note: **suggested
>   alternative**:
>
> In file included from C:\Users\edwin\Dropbox\Projects\Arduino
>   project\libraries\arduino_163901\src/ArduinoJson/**StaticJsonDocument**.hpp:8:0,

To solve this issue you can roll back to the previous version. Version 5.13.2 works for me.

Comment: Thanks I am going to give it a try later this week. I moved to Adafruit IO which worked. Still going to try how it works and looks like using the Azure IOT hub.

Comment: @borreltijd Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Rolling back to version 5.x worked and I do not have a compiler error anymore. I uploaded the sketch to my Feather Huzzah and used the serial monitor for further configuration as per tutorial.